# How to move all content down by 10px (Android in eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to move all the contents of my page down by about 10 pixels. I have tried to select all and drag down but the layout gets all messy. This is due to the relative layout. Is it possible to just shift everything down by a bit without ruining the layout? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `android:paddingTop` attribute of the RelativeLayout.  It accepts values in `px`, `dp`, and `sp` (so you're looking at `android:paddingTop="10px"` though the convention is to use `dp` for "density-independent pixels").  If it doesn't work, you can try adding another View at the top of your layout whose `android:layout_height` is 10 pixels.